# C++ unique_ptr errors when mixing with C functions

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm mixing C and C++ code and I've run into problems.  Below is the code that won't compile:

```
unique_ptr<char[]> buf(new char[buflen]);
snprintf(buf, buflen, procfd, fd);
```

Resulting in the error:

> wrapper_current.cpp:85:37: error: cannot convert `‘std::unique_ptr<char []>’` to `‘char*’` for argument ‘1’ to `‘int snprintf(char*, size_t, const char*, ...)’`

I thought that `unique_ptr` looked like a normal pointer to whatever is using it.
Is there a workaround for this?
If using `snprintf` is not possible then is there some C++ method that emulates `snprintf`?

Comment: Look through some [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr). There's no `operator T`.

Comment: No. If `unique_ptr` looked like a normal pointer to *whatever* is using it, it would *be* a normal pointer. `unique_ptr` looks like a normal pointer only in specific limited set of usage scenarios.

Comment: It may walk like a duck and quack like a duck, but it's still a `unique_ptr`. If you need a raw pointer to pass to a C function you can retrieve it from the `unique_ptr` with `buf.get()`.

Comment: **+1**: I'm not sure where all the downvotes on this question are coming from, but this is actually a well-formed question. Sure, the answer might be obvious to some, but it doesn't deserve being down-voted.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

#### Introduction

`std::unique_ptr<T>`  has overloads to make it feel like a *raw-pointer*, but it cannot implicitly turn into `T*` (since it has no overload of *operator T*). The overloaded operators of relevance are:

- `operator[]`; used to access the *Nth* element of the underlying resource (`T[]` required) and;
- `operator->`; used to access a member of the underlying resource, and;
- `operator *`; used to get a reference to the underlying resource.

These operators acts as a "proxies" to the underlying resource, we are still invoking them on a *std::unique_ptr*, and `buf` in your example will always be of type `std::unique_ptr`.

<sup>**Note**: A *unique_ptr* can explicitly be converted to *bool*, this is to make it possible to have `if (ptr) ...` and related expressions; ie. making it behave like a *raw-pointer* would in such context.</sup>

---

#### Explanation/Solution

*printf*-related functions are made to work with *raw-pointers*, which is kinda obvious since *smart-pointers* aren't even a part of *C* (where the function originally comes from).

If you'd like to get a *raw-pointer* to the resource that the *std::unique_ptr* currently manages, suitable to be passed to *printf*, call  [`your_unique_ptr.get`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/get) as in the below:

```
snprintf (buf.get (), buflen, procfd, fd);
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer and to all those who have contributed to answering my question.  It all works now.